# What is the mechanism behind antibiotic resistance and how can it be mitigated or prevented?

Tags: bacteriology, human-physiology

What causes antibiotic resistance, and how can we combat it? I am interested in the mechanisms behind antibiotic resistance and strategies to prevent it in bacteria.

Comment: We expect people to show at least some effort to solve a question by themselves. So, what have you found out? This is marked as homework which is used similar for low effort questions here.